# interactive map using tmap package with RMarkdown

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to write a report about my program and to show my work using RMarkdown. However, the map that I am currently using is generated by `tmap` package.

The shapefile can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s3ytgp2edm8p96b/AAAp0SJ8P7xfuVpiQNaCaqeqa?dl=0)

The way that I make it interactive using R is

```
library(tmap)
library(rgdal)
map <- readOGR("Malaysia SHP", "MYS_adm1")
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(map) + tm_polygons()
```

This would generate an interactive map that we can directly access from R.

I want to include this in my *RMarkdown* and still make it interactive. I know there is a package called `leaflet` that is usually used to create an interactive map. Is there any way to create an interactive map using `tmap` in *RMarkdown* without using `leaflet`?

Any helps would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for this bug report! It is now fixed in the development version.
See https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap how to install this.

If you cannot install the development version, a workaround is:

```
tmap_leaflet(tm_shape(map) + tm_polygons())
```

It coerces a tmap object to a leaflet object.